# yGuard NoSuchMappingException all external dependencies

Tags: java, maven, exception, obfuscation, yguard

I can't get yGuard to work with any external dependencies. All cases i'm getting error like `NoSuchMappingException: No mapping found for: Class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`.

My code:

**Main class:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SomeObj someObj = new SomeObj(2, "Hello");
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.print(someObj);
    }
}
```

**SomeObj:**

Just POJO with 2 fields: `Integer integerValue` & `String stringValue`.

**SomeClass:**

```
public class SomeClass {
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public void print(SomeObj someObj) throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(someObj));
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fsdfsfsd</groupId>
    <artifactId>fsdfsfsd</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainclass>com.mycompany.Main</mainclass>
        <jackson.version>2.9.9</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <id>obfuscate</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <property name="runtime_classpath"
                                          refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                                <taskdef name="yguard" classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask"
                                         classpath="${runtime_classpath}"/>
                                <yguard>
                                    <inoutpair
                                            in="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"
                                            out="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}_obfuscated.jar" />

                                    <externalclasses>
                                        <pathelement location="${maven.dependency.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core.jar.path}"/>
                                        <pathelement location="${maven.dependency.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind.jar.path}"/>
                                    </externalclasses>

                                    <shrink logfile="${project.build.directory}/yshrink.log.xml">
                                        <property name="error-checking" value="pedantic"/>
                                        <keep>
                                            <method name="void main(java.lang.String[])" class="com.mycompany.Main" />
                                            <class classes="public"/>
                                        </keep>
                                    </shrink>

                                    <rename mainclass="com.mycompany.Main" logfile="${project.build.directory}/yguard.log.xml">
                                        <property name="error-checking" value="pedantic"/>
                                        <keep>
                                            <class classes="public"/>
                                        </keep>
                                    </rename>
                                </yguard>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yworks</groupId>
            <artifactId>yguard</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And after `mvn clear compile package` i'm always getting in `yguard.log.xml` exception which starting this:

```
An exception has occured.
com.yworks.yguard.obf.NoSuchMappingException: No mapping found for: Class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
com.yworks.yguard.obf.NoSuchMappingException: No mapping found for: Class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at com.yworks.yguard.obf.ClassTree.mapClass(ClassTree.java:951)
    at com.yworks.yguard.obf.ClassTree.mapDescriptor(ClassTree.java:1450)
    at com.yworks.yguard.obf.classfile.ClassFile.remap(ClassFile.java:1107)
    at com.yworks.yguard.obf.GuardDB.remapTo(GuardDB.java:382)
```

I've tried to made point-to-point like in [official example](https://github.com/yWorks/yGuard/blob/master/examples/external_library/pom.xml), but i have no ideas what i'm doing wrong

Any ideas? Thanks a lot for tips